# how to test the accuracy of random forest model using a Table

Tags: r, random-forest

I am new to randomForest models and need help. 
I created a random forest of 500 trees from my train data.frame, and I created a set of response predictions for a specific variable. I need to compare the predictions to the original observations in a table. How do I do this? I tried just making `table(test, predictions)` but it's a little hard to understand what the table is even telling me.

Comment: Why not provide an example of your data and tables? That's not rhetorical.

Comment: the data is answers from a survey, with factor levels: strongly agree, agree, no answer, disagree, strongly disagree" I am asked to isolate the responses of one  survey question, and compare the responses to this question between the actual observed responses and a random forest nTree=500 responses. I made the random forest this way:
> rf1<- randomForest(Question5~., data=train)
and then the predicted
>p1<-predict(rf1,test, type ='response')
and then making the table ( p1, test$question5) just gives me a weird array of what i assume is where the answers had overlap? 
:

Answer (score 5):

Since you have not provided the data, I have tried to replicate it and here is the procedure I followed:

Replicating the data:

```
Level <- c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "no answer", "agree", "strongly agree")

Question5 <- c("strongly agree", "agree", "no answer", "disagree", "strongly disagree", "disagree", "no answer", "agree", "strongly disagree")
Question5 <- factor(Question5, levels=Level, ordered=T)
train <- data.frame(a=c(2,3,5,1,2,1,4,1,4), b=c(4,1,3,2,5,3,4,1,2), Question5)

Question5 <- c("strongly disagree", "no answer", "agree", "strongly disagree", "disagree", "strongly agree", "no answer", "disagree", "strongly agree")
Question5 <- factor(Question5, levels=Level, ordered=T)
test <- data.frame(a=c(4,3,5,2,1,3,4,2,5), b=c(5,2,3,1,4,3,2,4,1), Question5)
```

Applying randomForest:

```
> library(randomForest)
> rf1 <- randomForest(Question5~., data=train, ntree=500)
> p1 <- predict(rf1, test, type='response')
> table(p1, test$Question5)
p1                  strongly disagree disagree no answer agree strongly agree
  strongly disagree                 0        0         2     0              1
  disagree                          0        1         0     0              0
  no answer                         1        0         0     1              0
  agree                             1        0         0     0              1
  strongly agree                    0        1         0     0              0
```

You should get a table similar to what I have got above when you perform this procedure with your data. When you add up the diagonal elements of this table, you will obtain the total number of correct predictions (1 out of 9 in the above case).

Answer (score 0):

Something I use to evaluate models is:

```
evaluate <- function(actuals, predictions){
  cf.matrix <- table(actuals,predictions)
  cf.precision <- cf.matrix[2, 2] / sum(cf.matrix[, 2])
  cf.prop_miss <- cf.matrix[2, 1] / sum(cf.matrix[2, ])
  cf.accuracy <- (cf.matrix[1, 1] + cf.matrix[2, 2]) / sum(cf.matrix)
  cf.TruePositiveRate <- cf.matrix[2,2] / sum(cf.matrix[2, ])
  cf.FalsePositiveRate <- cf.matrix[1, 2] / sum(cf.matrix[1, ])
  cf.prevalence <- sum(cf.matrix[2, ]) / sum(cf.matrix)

  output <- list(cf.matrix,cf.precision,cf.prop_miss,cf.accuracy,cf.TruePositiveRate,cf.FalsePositiveRate,cf.prevalence)
  names(output) <- c('confusion matrix','precision','percent missed','accuracy','True Positive', 'False Positive', 'prevalence')
  return(output)
}
```